# uploading image to firebase storage returns /data/user/0/..../file.path Url

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I have a registration method, where user can also register his/her outlet. I am having problem with uploading images, one is for profile image, the other is for the outlet logo. Profile image uploading works fine, returning Url is fine, fetching the image is also fine. However, although exactly the same method, uploading outlet logo returns weird URL: `"/data/user/0/..../cache/d2ff5f32-6c6b-435b-bc25-0f7730bfac4e/Screenshot_20230625-155857.png"`, which later does not return the image.

```
Future<bool> register(PetUser user) async {
final result = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: user.email!, password: user.password!);

firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value) {
  debugPrint(value);
  user.token = value!;
});

if (user.imageUrl != null) {
  final file = File(user.imageUrl!);
  if (await file.exists()) {
    user.imageUrl = await uploadImage(file);
  } else if (user.outletImage != null) {
    final files = File(user.outletImage!);
    if (await files.exists()) {
      user.outletImage = await uploadImageO(files);
    }
  }

  user.id = result.user!.uid;
  await usersCollection.doc(user.id).set(user.toJson());
  await usersCollection.doc(user.id).collection('ratings').doc('1').set({
    'numberOfRates': 0,
    'rating' : 0
  });
}
return true;
}
```

then images uploading methods are complete exact copies, with some minor differences:

```
Future<String> uploadImage(File file) async {
final task = storage.ref().child("user")
    .child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .child(const Uuid().v4()).putFile(file);
await task.whenComplete(() {});
return await task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
}

Future<String> uploadImageO(File files) async {
final ref = storage.ref().child("outlet_images")
    .child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .child(const Uuid().v4()).putFile(files);
ref.whenComplete(() {});
return await ref.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
}
```

I cannot find where the mistake is? Please, help me. Thanks!

Comment: `putFile` is async, should'n you use `await` in both cases to wait for the upload task to complete? Also, It might be useful the test if the return value from `putFile` (after awaiting it) is `TaskState.success` to be sure it is really uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the code jumps from the first condition to the end, skipping the `else if` for the outletImage, so i brought them together in the first IF condition, and it worked. Maybe will be helpful to newbies like me

```
Future<bool> register(PetUser user) async {
final result = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: user.email!, password: user.password!);

firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value) {
  debugPrint(value);
  user.token = value!;
});

if (user.imageUrl != null && user.outletImage != null) {
  final file = File(user.imageUrl!);
  final files = File(user.outletImage!);

  if (await file.exists() && await files.exists()) {
    user.imageUrl = await uploadImage(file);
    user.outletImage = await uploadImageO(files);
  } else if (user.imageUrl != null && user.outletImage == null) {
      final file = File(user.imageUrl!);
      if (await file.exists()) {
        user.imageUrl = await uploadImage(file);
      }
  }
  
  user.id = result.user!.uid;
  await usersCollection.doc(user.id).set(user.toJson());
  await usersCollection.doc(user.id).collection('ratings').doc('1').set({
    'numberOfRates': 0,
    'rating' : 0
  });
}
return true;
}
```